# SQLite Select different where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I'm stuck with queries. Basically I want to get two results of the same field, according to two where clauses, then.
Sum (field1) when (ins_n = 0) and sum (field1) when (ins_n = 1). I hope I explained. Now I can only do so when (ins_n = 0)

```
"SELECT " +
"SUM(field1) AS incasso1, " +                
"FROM Movimentinegozio WHERE ins_n = 0 ";
```

Comment: `select ... where ins_n in (0, 1) group by ins_n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ins_n = 0 THEN field1 END) AS incasso0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ins_n = 1 THEN field1 END) AS incasso1
FROM Movimentinegozio
WHERE ins_n IN (0, 1);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d78d9/1/0)**</kbd>

If you need result in two rows use [`@Marc B`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) suggestion:

```
SELECT ins_n, SUM(field1) AS incasso
FROM Movimentinegozio
WHERE ins_n IN (0, 1) 
GROUP BY ins_n
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d78d9/9/0)**</kbd>